# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'VCOMPD.lib'

Tags: visual-c++, linker, linker-errors

I am receiving the above link error while trying to compile my c++ program.
I am working on vs2010 express and the message appears only in debug mode.

Can somebody help me because I tried to resolve this issue with propositions I gathered after searching and all failed.

(I am not linking my program against this lib file - at least I have not included it in my linking libraries)

Comment: OpenMP is not supported in the Express edition.

Comment: So how can I overcome this issue and get my program compile? Why this is only happening in debug Mode?